# Disable mouse scroll wheel in Cesium

Tags: javascript, scroll, mousewheel, cesiumjs

I have a map using Cesium via ol3-cesium. This map does not use the full space of the website. I am trying to disable scrollwheel zooming, so that I can keep scrolling up and down the web page with the mouse scroll wheel.

I can disable mouse scroll wheel zooming with:

```
map3d.getCesiumScene().screenSpaceCameraController.enableZoom = false;
```

However, that doesn't bring me back the normal page scrolling. The scrolling event seems to be captured by Cesium and not propagated.

How can I get Cesium to ignore or propagate the mouse scroll wheel to the browser, so that the user can scroll the page even if the cursor is on top of the map?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.
Listen for the wheel event in the cesium container and when it happens, just scroll the window.

```
var pageStep = 25;
document.getElementById('yout-cesium-container-id').addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
    if (event.deltaY < 0) {
        window.scroll(0, window.pageYOffset - pageStep);
    } else {
        window.scroll(0, window.pageYOffset + pageStep);
    }
});
```

You still need to disable the zoom in and out in Cesium.

```
map3d.getCesiumScene().screenSpaceCameraController.enableZoom = false;
```

Comment: That is a nice workaround, thanks. It looks a bit choppy compared to the browser's smooth scrolling, but it will do the trick in the absence of a more native solution.

Comment: There is [scrollBy()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollBy) which seems to do the same smooth scrolling that the browser does by default (although that page says it's not available on IE or safari currently).  I was able to get it to work by replacing the body of the listener function in this answer with `window.scrollBy({top:event.deltaY, behavior:'smooth'});` .